# How to Set Property Value in Objective-C the Right Way

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I might've jumped into Objective-C a little too fast and assumed I knew enough about memory management to dive in. Turns out I wasn't.

Fast forward a bit and I've caught up ... for the most part. One of my last remaining questions regards the @property/@synthesize process and setting those values properly.

I've often seen this:

```
SomeObject *obj = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
self.obj = obj;
[obj release];
```

It makes sense, but I wonder if this accomplishes a similar enough thing to be an alternative:

```
self.obj = [[[SomeObject alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Would that be acceptable anywhere you might set the value of the `@property`, `obj`? Or is direct access to the instance variable preferred over both of those in the `init` method?

```
obj = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Definitely related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596310/objects-creation-and-instantiation-in-objective-c) that discusses half of my question. The `autorelease` part of my question is referenced in one of the answers, but has not been confirmed.

So my questions still remain:

1. Is `autorelease` a valid alternative in this situation?
2. Can `autorelease` be used this way in the `init` method, or should the instance variable always be set directly in the `init` method?

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842641/best-way-to-set-a-retained-property-to-a-newly-created-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is that in your first example, `obj` is released immediately (although it was presumably retained by the `self.obj` setter). The two examples are effectively the same.

Note that going forward, we can rely on ARC to deal with releasing objects at the appropriate time, so you can write:

```
self.obj = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
```

and let ARC worry about where to put the release or autorelease.

**Update:** You seem to be asking how things are different inside an `-init` method. The two things you need to be aware of are:

1. When possible, you should access ivars directly in `-init` and `-dealloc` methods. The idea is to avoid problems that could occur if your accessors are overridden by a subclass. There are a number of other questions here on SO that address this in greater depth, such as:

   [Why shouldn't I use Objective C 2.0 accessors in init/dealloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-objective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc)
2. If you're creating an object in an `-init` method and assigning it to an ivar, you probably don't want to release it until a later point, such as `-dealloc`. So yes, it's fine  in an `-init` method to not release the objects you create (so long as you keep a reference to them), but you'll still balance that `+alloc` with a `-release` in `-dealloc`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense then. So what happens in the `init` method or when the instance variable would have been `nil`? Should it be set directly, or is using the setter with `autorelease` fine?

Comment: What do you mean by 'what happens in the init method?'? `-init` doesn't care about your variables. `+alloc` returns a pointer to an object. Then the `-init` message is sent to that object, and it returns a (probably the same, but possibly different) pointer. You can assign that to a local variable, as in your first example. Or you can assign it directly to a property, as in your second example. Or you can assign it directly to an instance variable if you don't mind managing the memory yourself. The setter with `autorelease` is fine.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I meant in the `init` method of a class I would be writing. I was reading that the 'rules' can be different here because the instance variables are `nil` so calling `obj = [[SomeObject alloc] init];` would be correct instead of releasing in any way. Was that just a bunch of bologna?

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking. I'll update my answer above rather than trying to squeeze it all into a comment.